# Transferring data from a Query to a variable

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello I'm developing an App but it stopped because I have a problem that I'm going to explain it:
I made a Login screen to my app located in `main.dart` file. In this file I do a query to my server using a PHP file using `JSON` to encode the query and in the dart file i use the `Json.decode` to validate the data.

Now the question is how can I put that data in a variable to use it in another Widget? What I'm trying to do is putting the name and the email from the query to my side-bar menu which is my `HomePage` Widget.

Dart:

```
class LoginStates extends State<Login>{

@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

TextEditingController user=new TextEditingController();

TextEditingController pass=new TextEditingController();

Future<List> _login() async{

  final response =await 

http.post("https://exclinico.com/admin/FlutterClases/login.php", body: {

    "correo": user.text,

    "password": pass.text,

  });

  print(response.body);

 var datosusuario = json.decode(response.body);


 if (datosusuario.length==0) {

  Mensaje(context);

   }

   else{

     Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/mainpage');

   }

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$usuario=$_POST['correo'];

$contraseña=$_POST['password'];

$contraseña=base64_encode($contraseña);

$query=$conexion->query("SELECT*FROM paciente WHERE correo_elect = '$usuario' AND password='$contraseña'");

$resultado=array();

while($fetchData=$query->fetch_assoc()){

 $resultado[]=$fetchData; 

}

$_SESSION['correo'] = $usuario;

 echo json_encode($resultado);

?>
```

I need to transfer the name and email to `HomePage`. Sorry for the English BTW! Thanks.